# NodeJS and body-parser

Tags: node.js, body-parser

I tried to make a golden book width nodeJS. So I use body-parser to get my form's values and it works until I try to verify if my form is empty by this way :

```
app.post('/', (request, response) => {
if(request.body.message === undefined) {
    console.log('Message : ' + request.body.message);

}
```

When I try to run my server and test my form by pushing informations, the loading of the page is infinite.

Can you help me please ?

Here, the full code :

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// moteur de template
app.set('view engine','ejs');


// MIDDLEWARE
app.use('/assets', express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// ROUTE
app.get('/', (request, response) =>{
    response.render('pages/index');
});

app.post('/', (request, response) => {
    if(request.body.message === undefined) {
        console.log('Message : ' + request.body.message);

    }
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is infinite, because you never finish it.

You can do it by simple

```
response.end()
```

in your request handler or if you want to return something to a client, then you can use

```
response.send({message: 'hello there'})
```